# $GLOBALS['TYPO3_REQUEST']->isFrontend return null

Tags: php, typo3, global-variables, typoscript, typo3-11.x

I have a error in frontend on my subpages.

```
Argument 1 passed to TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\ApplicationType::fromRequest() must 
implement interface Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface, null given
```

It's called in this extension `andersundsehr/aus-driver-amazon-s3`

It's `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_REQUEST']->isFrontend` who is passed in `fromRequest()`

When I debug `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_REQUEST']` in frontend, it's working on the root page, but not in subpages.

I work on TYPO3 v11 in local (want to upgrade online)

Did you have any idea how can I declare `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_REQUEST']` on any page of my website ?

Thanks for your help.

I only want access to my subpages

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned extension needs to cover this issue. Simply `providing` a created valid frontend request object in `$GLOBAL['TYPO3_REQUEST']` would
be quite challenging to be "correct" - and not correct in many cases anyway.

The soultion would be to:

- Check the extension issue tracker if that issue has already been reported, fixed.
- If not, report it there `[1]`
- If already fixed, update to the version containing the fix, using composer patchets to get it earlier or to hope(gently ask) for a release with that fix.

[1] https://github.com/andersundsehr/aus_driver_amazon_s3/issues